# how to locate files with helm-for-files using ssh

Tags: helm, helm-for-files

I want to use helm-for-files to search for files on remote hosts. It would be great if I could use /ssh: like in helm-find-files to display all hosts in my ssh config file. After choosing one host I'd like to have the recent file and locate helm display like in helm-for-files instead of a dirtree.